# Get back ⌘+F2 shortcut back from app

Tags: macos, shortcut

An application that I use, Pomodoro Time Pro, captures ⌘+F2 globally (so I can't use it with any other app). It doesn't use it for any purpose nor is there a way to unset the shortcut. Their support have acknowledged this as a bug but even after four months and multiple contacts, they are "still fixing it as soon as possible."

I'm using Mac OS X 10.11 and was wondering if there is a way to disable ⌘+F2 for this app somehow.

Comment: have you tried using a third party app for this,There a free app BetterTouchTool that manages app shortcuts and it's very easy to use : http://www.boastr.de/.
 I'm pretty sure it's doable via modifying a Pomodoro or a system file, you may want to check `ls ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Pomodoro*` or just ask their support for that file tell them you want to modify it yourself.

Comment: `$ defaults read com.xwavesoft.pomodoromac` returns a bunch of info with startShortcut and stopShotcut keys etc. Nothing in that file seems like it can be edited to fix the problem.

Comment: I've contacted the developer twice in 4-5 months but all they have done so far is to promise to fix the problem as soon as possible :(

Comment: Thanks Heavens, the developer has fixed the issue in the latest version. They have also renamed the app to 'Be Focused Pro'.